# Can I configure AirPort Express from iOS?

Tags: wireless-networking, airport-express, ios

An AirPort Express makes a nice travel companion for an iPad or iPod Touch. However, it seems to require a Mac to run the AirPort Utility for the initial setup (passwords and stuff). Is there any way to configure it from an iOS device? Third-party app? Or is there a web interface like with other routers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a native iOS utility (app) from apple that allows you to configure your Airport Express, Airport Extreme, or Time Capsule from iOS.  [AirPort Utility](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airport-utility/id427276530?mt=8)

Requirements: Compatible with iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad. Requires iOS 5.0 or later.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently (according to [this discussion](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2407780&start=0&tstart=0)) there is no iOS Airport Utility nor browser access to configure the AX, but it can save up to 5 configurations.  So you could pre-configure it and save the configuration.  You'd still have to remember to select your travel configuration before you leave home but at least you wouldn't have to walk through it each time.  If you'd forgetten to do that, and you had AirPort Utility for Windows on a USB stick, you might also be able use a borrowed or public machine long enough to switch it to its travel configuration.
(Thanks for asking this - I got curious and learned a lot I hadn't known about the AX).

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](http://www.9to5mac.com/71346/apple-now-lets-you-set-up-an-airporttime-capsule-from-your-ios-device/), this will come with iOS 5, as part of the big drive to (finally!) make iOS devices work without a PC.